# Why does chrome.runtime.sendMessage result in my callback being called twice when there's an error?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have the following code in my background script. I send a message to another app, but if it fails, this gets called twice (**note: my callback is called twice. My code calling `sendMessage` is only called once**)!

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    otherAppId,
    someObject,
    function (response)
    {
        var lastError = chrome.runtime.lastError;

        //This likely means it doesn't exist ("Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.")
        if ( lastError && lastError.message.indexOf( "not exist" ) !== -1 )
        {
            ///This gets called twice!
            console.log( "we're here twice?!" );
        }

        //This is called once
        else console.log( "Was successful, so called only once" );
    }
);
```

Is there a way to cancel it so it stops trying again? Why does an error result in two calls to my callback?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, file it at http://crbug.com. Include a full app if possible to speed up developer's ability to reproduce and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was defining my own `Function.prototype.bind` (in a JS library I'd included) and this caused the issue! No idea why this causes so many errors and causes the callback to fire twice but removing that makes all the errors go away!

Comment: The internals of the chrome extension system use bind. If you redefine this function, weird things will start happening. However, we could and should protect against this. It would be great if you could file a bug about this as Vincent suggested. You can cc Vincent and myself on the bug.

Comment: @BenWells How do I cc you guys on this? Do I need your emails? I assume I'm putting the bug report at: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @BenWells how do I cc you on that bug?